# Cast argument to string before splitting and comparison to another string value

Tags: sql

How to cast/change the datatype of correct_category to string during split?

```
IF(SPLIT(main.correct_category,'^') = main.submitted_category, 1,0) as decision_correct,

IF(SPLIT(main.correct_category,'^') != main.submitted_category, 1,0) as decision_incorrect
```

```
Error:
No matching signature for operator = for argument types ARRAY<STRING> and <STRING>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please tag which DBMS you are using (SQL Server, mySQL, etc)

Comment: The error message isn't about the column but the return value from the SPLIT function.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I need to select the first element at index 1 as it is returning an array

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL, which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the STR() function?

```
IF(SPLIT(STR(main.correct_category),'^') = main.submitted_category, 1,0) as decision_correct,
IF(SPLIT(STR(main.correct_category),'^') != main.submitted_category, 1,0) as decision_incorrect
```